# Remake Django Model Every time

Tags: python, django, sqlite, python-2.7, django-models

I started making my project without realizing that every time I populate my DB table it adds to the existing data. I thought it would delete the old data and add the new data!

Is there any way to do what I've described above easily? If not how would you suggest I do something like this?

Comment: You wrote 'every time I change my model data', do you really mean 'every time I change my model class'?

Comment: So I have a csv file that populates my module. Every time I change the csv that happens.

Comment: Can you please rewrite your question to include the CSV part. In python, a module is python code, you cannot populate a module from a CSV file; but you can populate a DB table, or a model. Please try to be as clear as possible, you can include source code (well formatted, please). I'm leaving today, but if you can update your question to a clearer one, I can help you with an answer tomorrow. :)

Comment: You say the question has been fixed but we are no nearer to understanding it. Everytime you populate a database the data get's added to the existing data regardless of what programming language and platform you use

Comment: Do you want to keep the old data ? if not , just blow it away and insert the new one. If you want to keep the old data, may be "versioning" might be a good approach - where every insert would have a specific version number.

Comment: I don't want to keep the old data! How can I blow it away and insert the new one?

Comment: @e4c5 When I say "it has been fixed" I mean I edited the question to what he proposed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be using migrations:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/

You should read the Models tutorial, toward the end it talks about migrations:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/

If you are using Django 1.6 or previous, you should use south to manage your migrations:
http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Migrations helps managing versions of the Model, every time you change your model, you create a migration and apply it. Creating the migration can be automatic, south and django >= 1.7 both can find changes in your models and create the migration files. The migration files are python files capable of making the changes to the DB. Then you apply the migration and the change is done in the DB. To create the migrations, and to apply them, you must manually run a command.

The reason for having such files is version management, you can get back to a previous migration and have your DB as before. Read the documentation to learn the simple commands to do it, you surely will get it in a couple hours.